# SQL help on count in certain ID

Tags: sql

Do you know how to display only the lines in table for same ID where `col3` is not 'X'?
*e.g.*, in the following table, it should display only `ID` 2 (as all the `col2` are `null`)

```
 ID | col1 | col2 | col3
 ---+------+------+-----
  1 | 0    | 0    | X
  1 | D    | C    | null
  1 | D    | C    | null
  2 | 0    | 0    | null
  2 | D    | C    | null
  2 | D    | C    | null
```

It should work for all `ID` with some many line by `ID` and only the same `ID` with all line having `null`.

Comment: Do you need just the ID in the result, on the entire rows for id=2?

Comment: hello, yes the entire row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to get records where ID does not have at least one X in col 3 for other records:

```
SELECT Y.* 
   FROM Your_Table Y
WHERE Y.ID NOT IN (SELECT X.ID FROM YOUR_TABLE X WHERE X.ID=Y.ID AND X.COL3='X')
```

Comment: thanks
And if i'm in the case where i have two tables :
SELECT Y.* , Z.*
   FROM Your_Table Y
   inner join TABLE2 Z on Z.ID=Y.ID
WHERE Z.ID NOT IN (SELECT Z.ID FROM YOUR_TABLE Z WHERE ZID=Y.ID AND X.COL3='X')

Something like that 
I want to display same condition : 
1 . Display all ids without X in col 3
2. Display also the ids existing in table Y and not in Z (means that they don't have X because they don't exist in table Z)

Please advise
Thanks

Comment: Can u please post as new question

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMS support 3 valued logic - True, False, and Undefined. NULL <> 3 is undefined, since NULL is an unknown value. You need to handle NULLs explicitly.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Your_Table
 WHERE col3 <> X
    OR col3 IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where (col1 = col2) and (col3 <> 'X')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions or `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.col3 = 'X');
```